# Query not pulling complete data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two sheets -- the sheet I am pulling data from and the another sheet which contains a query; however, it is only pulling the header and not complete data.

```
=QUERY((ARRAYFORMULA(Data_frm_Invoices!$A$1:$U),"Select H Where C >= "&C1&" and C <= "&C2,1)
```

Comment: Please try removing the `ARRAYFORMULA`. It is does not solve, please problem a copy of your sheet.

Comment: I have tried but its not resolving my problem . https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q8FCvkVl-2X7T9UR22LqnunHy4UZ89G93EsM4OfmgQE/edit#gid=233925968

Comment: Please [make it public](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cchange-who-your-link-is-shared-with)

Comment: In some locales "&C1&" must be done with single quotes